# Character between every letter

Tags: java, string, character

In Java, I have a string for eg. "Test"

I want to change the string to have a 1 before every letter like so:

"1T1e1s1t"

This is just for testing as I will change it to what I want later on.

I know I could just make the string like that, but the user inputs a word. I want it *then* to be formatted.

Anyway I can achieve this?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I cant, dont know how :P Trying things now....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
String sample="Test";
String append="1";
StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer(sample.length()*append.length());
for(int i=0; i<sample.length(); i++) {
    sb.append(append).append(sample.charAt(i));
}
System.out.println(sb.toString(); //result
```

The append() method can take all primary types.

You can replace StringBuffer by a StringBuilder if it does not require to be thread safe.

Comment: If you know the final size of your String, create the buffer with the capacity in the constructor to avoid performance issue

Comment: Perfect! Just one more thing, is there a way I can choose a completely different 'append character' for every letter? eg. 1T2e3s4t but it works for any length of letters.

Comment: Because what I was actually going for was making a random number appear before each character so one time it might be '1T2e' and other '9T3e'

Comment: No, you were spot on with question, now i'm just asking if the above is possible. If that works, your answer will be perfect.

Comment: I did it without running my IDE, I may forgot parenthesis or something easy to fix

Comment: -1 (and for future readers): This code is suboptimal (the only appropriate part was allocating a correct buffer size). Compared to [amit's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25103433/3622940)(Which was here first anyway) you've declared the literal String `"1"` instead of using `1` or `'1'` (Which is less efficient). To add to it, you have a syntax error on the last line you never fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can be done.

Use a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to construct a new string with the modified properties, by iterating the characters, and for each character `c`, and `1` and `c` to the builder.

```
String s = "test"; //your string, could be supplied by user from input as well
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); //the StringBuilder
//this iterates the string and puts in the builder 1 before any character
for (char c : s.toCharArray()) sb.append(1).append(c); 
//done. print the new string:
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

[Here's the code on ideone](https://ideone.com/8j5wr7).

Answer (score 0):

Try tis

```
public class Foo
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        String s1 = "Test" ;
        String s2 = "" ;

        for(int i=0; i<s1.length(); i++)
        {
            s2 += ( "1" + s1.charAt(i) ) ;
        }
        System.out.println(s2) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that theoretically it is an inefficient solution, as it takes `O(n^2)` time due to the need to create a new String object from scratch each iteration. (JIT might optimize it for you however)

Comment: Yes indeed, it is a bit inefficient. I saw your example after I posted mine.

Comment: If anything, avoid concatenating strings in a loop, use `StringBuffer` instead.